# Set HttpContext.Current.User from Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I have a security manager in my application that works for both windows and web, the process is simple, just takes the user and pwd and authenticates them against a database then sets the  Thread.CurrentPrincipal with a custom principal. For windows applications this works fine, but I have problems with web applications.

After the process of authentication, when I'm trying to set the Current.User to the custom principal from Thread.CurrentPrincipal this last one contains a GenericPrincipal. Am I doing something wrong? This is my code:

Login.aspx

```
protected void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SecurityManager.Authenticate("user","pwd"); // This is where I set the custom principal in Thread.CurrentPrincipal
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                        "user",
                        DateTime.Now,
                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                        false,
                        "");

    string ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket);
    HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, ticket);
    Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie);    
    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl("user", false));
}
```

Global.asax (This is where the problem appears)

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (authCookie == null)
        return;

    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
    {                
        HttpContext.Current.User = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal; //Here the value is GenericPrincipal
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: You need to set the principal on every request.

Forms authentication uses it's own assignment of the principal on each request. That's why you are seeing the `GenericPrincipal`

I usually reassign my custom prinicpal in OnPostAuthenticate when the standard authentication mechanism is done.

Answer (score 1):

JFYI, you can replace

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity) { }
```

with

```
FormsIdentity formsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User as FormsIdentity;
if (formsIdentity != null & formsIdentity.IsAuthenticated) { }
```

to reduce the length of if-clause

Answer (score 0):

The Intellisense tells me that `HttpContext.Current.user` and `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` are both of type `System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal`.

If I understand correctly, this means that the statement `HttpContext.Current.User = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;` will assign the value of thread principal to the httpcontext user without any casting or conversion.

I don't see where exactly in your code you are setting the value of the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, but I suggest you carefully examine how you set the principal.  I recommend that you put breakpoints on this code and run it in the debugger.  See what is happening line-by-line.

Comment: I set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal in the first line in the login page, this is the process where authenticates the user and set the custom principal, this works fine in windows environment, but the problems are in web.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the VB (orrible language) however this should answer your question ...

http://www.asp.net/security/videos/use-custom-principal-objects

Then change that line of code to something like ...

```
HttpContext.Current.User = (CustomPrinciple)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```

That should give you what you need.
Works perfectly for me :)

Comment: If you don't like VB.NET, there are many easy conversion tools available, such as this one: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score -2):

When you use Forms Based Authentication (FBA), you get a GenericPrincipal in ASP.NET. This is normal, you are not doing anything wrong.

What where you expecting ? You could use Windows Integrated Authentication in your ASP.NET app if you were expecting a WindowsPrincipal.

Comment: Well, I think you didn't unserstand the question, the GenericPrincipal can be changed to a custom principal, my answer is why when I put the custom principal to the thread.CurrentPrincipal in one layer of the application I can't access it in the web application. In any part of the question I mention WindowsPrincipal.