# Trying to obtain the current logged in user's ID for tracking fields

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

**I am following this really good tutorial to setup a BaseEntity class that will contain 5 fields:**
Active, DateCreated, UserCreated, DateModified, UserModified.
All of my entities that need these tracking fields will inherit from this class.

In the small tutorial below he shows me how to override the SaveChanges() method in my dbContext so that these fields will be set properly based on Creation/Updating.

**I am trying to figure out how I would store the current logged in user's ID rather than the Name to the UserCreated and UserModified fields**

Please let me know if the UserID shouldn't be what I am storing. This is always what I used to do in some of the webforms apps I created back in the day.

Also, what would be the best way to setup Active to always be true when adding new records. Should this be done in the db context also or within my BaseEntity class. I'm thinking I would create a function in the BaseEntity class called Disable() that will change Active=False.

[Please view the small tutorial that I am using](http://benjii.me/2014/03/track-created-and-modified-fields-automatically-with-entity-framework-code-first/)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom implementation of IIdentity/IPrincipal which contains the UserID. Then you can retrieve this value from the Context or Thread and cast it to the correct type.

[Set HttpContext.Current.User from Thread.CurrentPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850105/set-httpcontext-current-user-from-thread-currentprincipal)